# How to reload a page in testcafe cucumberjs

Tags: javascript, testing, automated-tests, testcafe, cucumberjs

I am using TestCafe with Cucumber.js and I don't know how to reload the page. Testcafe documentation says to use **.eval(() => location.reload(true))**
which gives me the following error:

> eval cannot implicitly resolve the test run in the context of which it should be executed. If you need to call eval from the Node.js API callback, pass the test controller manually via eval's `.with({ boundTestRun: t })` method first. Note that you cannot execute eval outside the test code.

Here is my BDD scenario:

```js
When('User hard refreshes the page', async () => {
    await testController
        .eval(() => location.reload(true))
});
```

Comment: Could you please specify your Cucumber integration package (testcafe-cucumber, gherking-testcafe or some other)?

Comment: Hi Andrey, I am using testcafe-cucumber. Like this demo: https://github.com/rquellh/testcafe-cucumber

Answer (score 3):

You can use [ClientFunction](https://devexpress.github.io/testcafe/documentation/guides/basic-guides/obtain-client-side-info.html#client-function-constructor) instead of `t.eval`:

```js
import { ClientFunction } from 'testcafe';

When('User hard refreshes the page', async () => {
    const reloadPage = ClientFunction(() => location.reload(true), { boundTestRun: testController });
    
    await reloadPage();
});
```

Comment: worth noting that it might actually be necessary to remove `{ boundTestRun: testController }`here.